# Intent does not work in android chrome app version 40

Tags: android, android-intent

Intent was working normally until android chrome version 38, but after updating to version 40, intent not work properly

```
if ( this.browser == "android+chrome/25+" ) {
    var chromeUrl = "intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;end";

    //All of syntax works well in chrome 38.
    //But, some syntax not work in chrome 40.
    window.open(chromeUrl);     // --> works well, but this brings up a pop-up screen
    window.location = chromeUrl;        // --> ERROR : ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
    window.location(chromeUrl);         // --> ERROR : ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
    window.location.href = chromeUrl;   // --> ERROR : ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
    window.location.href(chromeUrl);    // --> ERROR : ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

} else {
```

I don't want brings up a pop-up screen.

Need your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think I just answered this on your issue in the chromium issue tracker.  The issue is on the chromium issue tracker [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=459156).

The response with the "workaround", pasted from the issue:

> OK, I've found out that the window.location redirect via intent will
>   work, AS LONG as it is clicked from an external source or link on
>   page.  If you manually enter the address of the redirect page into the
>   address bar, the redirection / opening of the app will fail with said
>   error.
>
> So, sending a link to the redirect page in an email or SMS will work
>   just fine when the user clicks the link.  Manually typing the address
>   into the address bar will fail.  `window.location = chromeUrl;` should
>   work just fine.